# Java exceptions - try for the n'th time to return to the "try" statement block

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to make a call that might throw an exception due to server being down.
this is what i want to accomplish:

```
Server server = serverQueue.poll();
try {
     if (server==null){return null}
     server.makeConnection();

} catch (Exception e) {
     // try another server
     server = serverQueue.poll();
     // now return to try block?

}
```

So i have 5 servers and maybe in later stage i'll add some more. So i want to connect to
anyone of them in this manner. How can i return to the try block? is there anything such as a statement like this below in java?:

```
Server server = serverQueue.poll();
outerBlock:
try {
     if (server==null){return null}
     server.makeConnection();

} catch (Exception e) {
     // try another server
     server = serverQueue.poll();
     continue outerBlock;

}
```

Comment: The short answer is "use a Java loop statement".  You cannot make control jump backwards in Java except by using a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically a loop:

```
Server server = serverQueue.poll();
boolean connected = false;
while (!connected) {
    if (server == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
         server.makeConnection();
         connected = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
         // Presumably log something here, for management info

         // try another server
         server = serverQueue.poll();
    }
}
```

Or to avoid the duplication:

```
Server server;
boolean connected = false;
while (!connected) {
    server = serverQueue.poll();
    if (server == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
         server.makeConnection();
         connected = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
         // Presumably log something here, for management info
    }
}
```

You might consider isolating the "find a server" part of that into its own function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `try` block inside a simple loop, either `while` or `for`.

Comment: like to set a boolean to false first and after the connection to set it to true and all that in a while condition? seems ugly

Comment: There are a few ways to do it, but you need to control the looping, and the decision to give up.

Answer (score 0):

ou can use a for loop

```
 Server server;     

for(int i=0;i<=numberOFServers-1;i++){
   server = serverQueue.poll();
      try {
           if (server==null){return null}
           server.makeConnection();

          } catch (Exception e) {

             System.out.println("Server : " +i+ " could not establish connection");
          }
 }
```